# Bad XPath or bad JSoup?

Tags: java, xpath, syntax, html-parsing, jsoup

**Please note:** that although this question directly involves a Java HTML parsing library called [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), I really believe its an XPath question at heart (and by solution).

We have an internal web app that serves an HTML page, `fizz.html`. On this page there is an important ID number that another process needs to be able to fetch anytime it runs. This ID changes periodically/predictably; hence, one day, the ID in the HTML page might be "394959". Another day it might be "248483", etc. For reasons outside the context of this question, this HTML page is the **only way** to obtain the ID.

So I'd like to use JSoup to hit the URL of the HTML page and parse the ID using Xpath selectors.

The HTML page (jsFiddle):

> http://jsfiddle.net/B5zvV/

The ID in question here can be found on Line 238 of the jsFiddle:

```
<a href="/chain/admin/config/editRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450">
```

It's the `repositoryId`, in this case it's currently "28049450".

My JSoup code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://myapp.example.com/fizz.html").get()    // See the jsFiddle above
Elements repoIdElems = doc.select("//*[@id=\"panel-editor-list\"]/ul")
```

When I run this I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query '//*[@id="panel-editor-list"]/ul': unexpected token at '//*[@id="panel-editor-list"]/ul'
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.findElements(QueryParser.java:196)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:53)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:39)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:80)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:93)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(Element.java:252)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element$select.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.me.myorg.parser.ClientParser.executeIntegration(ClientParser.groovy:98)
    at com.me.myorg.parser.ClientParser$executeIntegration.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at com.me.myorg.parser.ClientParser.main(ClientParser.groovy:143)
```

So I ask: is this a bad XPath (most likely), or is something bad with how I'm using the JSoup API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jousp does not support xpath.   The select statement takes CSS selectors only.